# Get foreground cell jtable

Tags: java, swing

I have Jtable with record like this
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFqNB.jpg

I use the **JTable.prepareRenderer(...) method**.

But then i get getForeground it's wrong Color, this's my code so what's wrong??

JTable Code:

```
tb1_1 = new javax.swing.JTable(){
    public Component prepareRenderer (TableCellRenderer renderer, int rowIndex, int columnIndex){
        Component componenet = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, rowIndex, columnIndex);
        if(rowIndex %2 == 0){
            componenet.setForeground(Color.RED);
        }else{
            componenet.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        }
        return componenet;
    }
};
```

Class get Color:

```
public class GetColor {

    private int red;
    private int green;
    private int blue;
    private Color color;

    public GetColor(Color color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public boolean isColorRed() {
        return getRed() == 255 && getGreen() == 0 && getBlue() == 0;
    }

    private int getRed() {
        return color.getRed();
    }

    private int getGreen() {
        return color.getGreen();
    }

    private int getBlue() {
        return color.getBlue();
    }

}
```

Final this my code return **isRed**

```
int r = 2;
int cl = 3;
TableCellRenderer tcr = tb1_1.getCellRenderer(r, cl);
Component c = tcr.getTableCellRendererComponent(tb1_1, dtb.getValueAt(r, cl), false, false, r, cl);
GetColor gc = new GetColor(c.getForeground());
System.err.println(gc.isColorRed()); **// is will return false when get Cell have foreground color red**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking at the foreground color provided by the [default renderer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender),

```
Component c = tcr.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, model.getValueAt(r, cl), false, false, r, cl);
System.out.println(c.getForeground());
```

which is typically black.

```
java.awt.Color[r=0,g=0,b=0]
```

You probably want to look at the color provided by your `prepareRenderer()`,

```
Component c = table.prepareRenderer(tcr, r, cl);
System.out.println(c.getForeground());
```

which you set to red.

```
java.awt.Color[r=255,g=0,b=0]
```